# LDAP (389 Directory Service) and Pacemaker with Multi-Master

Tags: ldap, failover, high-availability, 389-ds, pacemaker

I'm trying to setup a pair of LDAP servers running 389 (formerly Fedora DS) in high availability using Pacemaker with a floating IP. In addition, 389 supports multi-master replication, where all changes on one node are automatically replicated on one or more other nodes.

I'm fairly close to having everything working. Failover works just fine. And multi-master replication works fine. However, my current Pacemaker config stops the directory service on the non-active node. Which means that the backup node is not receiving replication data from the other node.

What is the right way to setup Pacemaker so that:

1. LDAP directory services are *always* running on both nodes
2. Floating IP is assigned to one of the nodes
3. Failover occurs if the master node dies *or* LDAP service stops running on the master

Initially, my Pacemaker config looked like the following:

```
property stonith-enabled=false
property no-quorum-policy=ignore

rsc_defaults resource-stickiness=100

primitive elastic_ip lsb:elastic-ip op monitor interval="10s"
primitive dirsrv lsb:dirsrv op monitor interval="10s"
order dirsrv-after-eip inf: elastic_ip dirsrv
colocation dirsrv-with-eip inf: dirsrv elastic_ip
```

I then explored using Pacemaker *clones*:

```
property stonith-enabled=false
property no-quorum-policy=ignore

rsc_defaults resource-stickiness=100

primitive elastic_ip lsb:elastic-ip op monitor interval="10s"
primitive ldap lsb:dirsrv op monitor interval="15s" role="Slave" timeout="10s" op monitor interval="16s" role="Master" timeout="10s"

ms ldap-clone ldap meta master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=3 clone-node-max=1 notify-true

colocation ldap-with-eip inf: elastic_ip ldap-clone:Master
order eip-after-promote inf: ldap-clone:promote elastic_ip:start
order ldap-after-eip inf: elastic_ip ldap-clone
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't quite work. pengine complains that "ldap-clone: Promoted 0 instances of a possible 1 to master" and then stops the LDAP service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Pacemaker mailing list, we have a solution. The problem is that the LSB script for 389 doesn't understand the concept of master/slave. The easiest solution is to use a simple clone, rather than a master/slave clone. New Pacemaker configuration looks like the following:

```
property stonith-enabled=false
property no-quorum-policy=ignore

rsc_defaults resource-stickiness=100

primitive elastic_ip lsb:elastic-ip op monitor interval="10s"
primitive dirsrv lsb:dirsrv op monitor interval="15s" role="Slave" timeout="10s" op monitor interval="16s" role="Master" timeout="10s"
clone ldap-clone dirsrv
order ldap-after-eip inf: elastic_ip ldap-clone
colocation ldap-with-eip inf: elastic_ip ldap-clone
```